# How do I make an event *dependent* on local time in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

I want to create an event that triggers at **0800 local time** no matter where you are in the world. In other words, the event will **not** trigger simultaneously around the world. It will trigger at 0800 EST/EDT for users who define their timezone as EST/EDT, and then again at 0800 CST/CDT for users who define their timezone as CST/CDT.

I hope this makes sense. The problem I'm having is that Google calendar forces you to specify a timezone for every event and calendar, then it converts everything to UTC and then adjusts your local calendar accordingly. So if I make an event that happens at 0800 EST, it's going to trigger at 0800 EST and simultaneously at 0700 CST, because Google treats it as one world event rather than something that happens many times around the world over the course of a 24-hour period (like New Year's Day).

If you're wondering what practical applications this can have, I want to use it for events that happen in Animal Crossing. My 0800 is not the same as 0800 for a user in California, so if I shared my calendar with them, they'd see the event as starting at 0500, which is wrong.

Or maybe this example is more clear: If I set a custom Christmas event to begin at 0000 on 31 December EST, then people in California will see it beginning at 2100 on 30 December PST. This is a problem, since *their* Christmas won't begin for another 3 hours.

I think this would also have practical applications for Muslim prayer times, holidays, workout calendars, morning routines, sunrise/sunset times, and anything else that is based on **local times** and not UTC.

Somehow, the holiday calendars that Google offers are not constrained by this problem, and I don't know how they managed to work around it. So, is there any way for me to make an event that changes based on the user's local time?

That was a really long-winded way to explain a simple problem, but I worry that people will misunderstand if I'm not totally explicit.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Google Calendar doesn't have a built-in feature to ignore or change the time zone to the local zone of the user but keeping the date and hour.

## Alternatives

Instead of sharing a calendar of Google Calendar share the calendar information in someway that the time-zone is not attached to the date-time data, like a CSV file, spreadsheet, project management file, mind-mapping file from an app that includes a calendar view, among others.

## References

- [Calendar Help](http://support.google.com/calendar)